# Is the painting at Lex Luthor's office real?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice, art

In the movie when Lex invites senator Finch to his private office, he points to an old oil painting depicting angels fighting with demons.

> Lex says then that the painting should be upside down, since demons will come from the sky.

At the end of the movie we can see the painting again but

> upside down, just as Lex wanted it to be, which (I guess) supposed to suggest incoming Darkseid.

Is this a painting created for the movie only or is it a real one?

Comment: It could be both.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

## Created by the film's art director from historical sources (according to a Reddit user who contacted him)

I've actually been searching for several days now for the name and/or origins of this painting, seen below:

[image]

I've turned up nothing, although there are various historical paintings in a similar style with a similar theme.

I did find the following, though: a Reddit user claims to have contacted the film's art director about the painting.

> **Chrysalis700:** I asked the art director of the movie and he sent me the following: It was created from various historic inspirations, then turned upside down.

([Comment permalink](https://www.reddit.com/r/DC_Cinematic/comments/4c09bv/spoilers_easter_eggs_you_noticed_in_the_film/d1kikf1))

I assume the user is referring to the supervising art director, **Troy Sizemore**.

If I had to pinpoint one of the primary influences, I would lean to Gustave Dore's "The Fall of the Rebel Angels" (1866):

[image]

Comment: My gosh, for a moment I read **Tom** Sizemore.

Answer (score -1):

[image: The Fall of the Rebel Angels Pieter Bruegel the Elder 1562]

I couldn't find the image shown but I found this painting which matched the title given.

> [The Fall of the Rebel Angels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fall_of_the_Rebel_Angels_(Bruegel)) by Pieter Bruegel the Elder.